# Using two DB context from different libraries

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two libraries with a DbContext in each. I am using both libraries in a windows forms app. When calling the DbContext I get following:

> 'An instance of 'AzureConfig' was set but this type was not discovered
>   in the same assembly as the 'DB' context. Either put the
>   DbConfiguration type in the same assembly as the DbContext type, use
>   DbConfigurationTypeAttribute on the DbContext type to specify the
>   DbConfiguration type, or set the DbConfiguration type in the config
>   file.

I can see other having same problem but not caused by having two context. I tried adding a DbConfiguration to each context. But then I get following:

> 'An instance of 'AzureConfig' was set but this type was not
>   discovered in the same assembly as the 'DB' context. Either put the
>   DbConfiguration type in the same assembly as the DbContext type, use
>   DbConfigurationTypeAttribute on the DbContext type to specify the
>   DbConfiguration type, or set the DbConfiguration type in the config
>   file.

The two DbConfiguration's are in each of the libraries with the DbContext.

Comment: You said "then i get" like some progress/difference had been made but these quoted messages look identical to me?

Comment: Your totally right. Got the wrong error in second I will correct.

Comment: When I tried to reproduce the other error I deleted both DbConfiguration. They wasnt added to any DbContext they was just a part of the project. Then it worked. So the conclusion is if you have to DbConfiguration's even if is not used then it fails. Deleting both totally resulted in a working sample.

Comment: So does it mean the error can no longer be reproduced? I'm confused as to whether you still need help or not

Comment: Hi I solved it. Thanks for your help. I add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I turned out if I deleted my two DbConfigurations it worked. First I just removed them as attributes. So they were just at part of the projects without being used. This still produced the error. If I totally deleted the classes, then the error stopped. No idea why.